# Xtext grammar variable definition/reference

Tags: java, grammar, xtext, ebnf

A `[any type]Realisation` grammar rule initialization should be a value or a reference to a predefined variable.
For Integer it looks similar like what you know from java:

```
public int i = 3;
```

Why does the following grammar throw an exception?

```
Integer returns ecore::ELong:
  (Plus|Minus)? INT;

IntegerRealisation:
  {Integer} Integer | 
  ref=[Integer];
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Generated EMF Model incomplete: The context 'IntegerRealisation' is not valid for type 'Integer'
Recommended contexts for type 'Integer': 
Other valid contexts for type 'Integer': .... The context 'IntegerRealisation' is valid for types: Integer, IntegerRealisation
```

Why does the first and the last line of the same error disagree each other?

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to reference an Integer literal instead of any other Integer typed variable. To implement s.th. like

```
public int i = 5; // 5 is a value
public int j = i; // i reference to a predefined variable
```

your grammar definition should look like

```
VariableDeclaration:
    modifiers+=Modifier* type=Type name=ID ('=' value=VariableValue)? ';';

VariableValue:
    TypedLiteral | VariableReference;

TypedLiteral:
    IntegerLiteral | ...;

IntegerLiteral:
    value=INTVAL;

terminal INTVAL returns ecore::ELong:
    (Plus|Minus)? INT;

VariableReference:
    ref=[VariableDeclaration|QualifiedName];
```

As you can see, it starts with the a rule to define a variable. This variable has a **name** attribute which is really important for the reference implementation later. The actual value allocation is optional (because I would do it like this!) Important at this point is the *abstract* rule `VariableValue` which will model either a literal (aka. constant value) or a reference to any other variable.

If you want to reference to any predefined variable you will use the other variables name, but **not** its value. Because of this reason we will also need the `VariableReference` which defines that we reference any other variable (in front of the pipe operator) by a (qualified) name (beind the pipe operator `|`).

To ensure type safety you have to implement the `yourdsl.validation.YourDslValidator` class to check whether the literal is compatible with the type and whether the type of a referenced variable is compatible to the type.

Edit: I optimized the grammar a little bit. The first version was a little bit unclear.

Answering your additional questions:

> What is the return type of VariableValue?

`VariableValue` itself is the common (but abstract) return type of all possible values. It is like `java.lang.Number` which is the super type of `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Double`, ...

The problem here is that the word *type* itself is ambiguous here. The *type* of the value will be `int` (`IntegerLiteral extends TypedLiteral extends VariableValue`) but the type of the AST node is either `IntegerLiteral` or `VariableReference`.

To determine the value type of a `VariableReference` you have to look into the `value` attribute of the referenced `VariableDeclaration` (`((VariableReference)vd1.getValue()).getRef().getValue()`). There will never be an `EString` value type!

To set a value to the `VariableDeclaration.value` attribute you need either an `IntegerLiteral` (most explicit TypedLiteral) or a `VariableReference`.

Comment: What is the return type of `VariableValue`? default is ecore::EString. But as `IntegerLiteral` returns a ELong and `VariableReference` (I guess) can only be EString or more likely EReference there will be no common supertype... The EMF class expects a `VariableValue` but that's not an instance!